# Ridge, Lasso or Elastic nets used in Accounting Research

Tags: references, lasso, ridge-regression, elastic-net

I am trying to come up with ideas for my master's thesis and was wondering why literature on the above mentioned regression methods within Accounting Research is non-existent?

I felt like the methods provide a solid way to get rid of the ... "inherent" multicollinearity in accounting data (i.e. if gross profit goes up, net income goes up. Or, if growth is high - the firm is more risky etc.) while yielding better results for prediction. Any help towards explaining the non-existence (or pointing me to some literature...) is greatly appreciated!

Additionally, I would like to know if the methods works on cross-sectional data too? That is, the groups change over years and coefficients are not estimated in a time-series fashion, but rather just at a "point in time" (i.e. yearly coefficients).

Comment: googling "accounting research regression regularization" (without the quotes, in google scholar) seems to give relevant hits, like https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2212567116303100  and others . try it

Comment: That, coincidentally, was the only paper I found and not related to the accounting "sub-field" I am focusing on. But thank you :)

Comment: Can you tell us which sub-field that is?

Comment: Actually, having re-read the article it doesn't really provide any explanation of what data (accounting items) it uses; only that is uses a set of bankrupt or not bankrupt firms. Not a very good article in my opinion.